# Leer un caracter sin presionar enter c++

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de hacer una especie de "juego" para el cual quiero que se mueva presionando las clásicas teclas WASD o las flechas direccionales, ¿Cómo hago para leer un caracter sin necesidad de presionar enter en C++? Sé que existe getch() pero quisiera una función o algún código que simule a esta, pues getch() pertenece a . Soy usuario de Windows.

Answer (score 0):

solo faltaria agregar los codigos de teclas que faltan:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;

#define ESC 27
#define ENTER 13

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (_kbhit()) // ENTRA AL IF CUANDO SE PRESIONA UNA TECLA
        {
            tecla = _getch();

            switch (tecla)
            {
            case 'W':
            case 'w':
                {
                    // MOVIMIENTO W
                    break;
                }

            case 'S':
            case 's':
                {
                    // MOVIMIENTO S
                    break;
                }

            case ESC:
                {
                    exit(0);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

lo que intentas hacer es un escenario por el cual una partícula se pueda mover la función getch es la indicada, solo tendrías que condicionar un poco y dibujar un pseudo escenario. Aqui te dejo unia idea para ver si te ayuda en tu proyecto.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
#define ESC 27

int main(){
    char key;
    int particula[2]={},i;

    while(true){
        //Condiciones de las teclas presionadas
        if(key==ESC)exit(0);
        if(key=='w')(particula[0]>0)?particula[0]--:printf("\a");
        if(key=='a')(particula[1]>0)?particula[1]--:printf("\a");
        if(key=='s')(particula[0]<24)?particula[0]++:printf("\a");
        if(key=='d')(particula[1]<9)?particula[1]++:printf("\a");

        //Dibuja los saltos y la particula segun su posición
        for(i=0;i<250;i++){
            if((particula[0]*10)+particula[1]== i){
                cout<<"O";
                break; //Dejar de digujar los saltos
            } else {
                cout<<"\t";
            }
        }

        //Espera que se posicióne una tecla y limpia el 'esenario'
        key = getch();
        system("cls");
        //printf("[x=%d, y=%d]", particula[0], particula[1]); //Ubicacion de la particula.
    }
    return 0;
}
```